# Is “suite” pronounced like “suit” in any native English-speaking countries?

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling, subcontinental-english

The word *suite* is pronounced the same  as  *sweet*  in  British  and  American  English. Surprisingly, even some  educated Indians  mispronounce  it  almost  similar  to   *suit*. Even name  boards  appear  in Indian  languages with  words  indicating  the  mispronunciation. One  Indian  professor  of  English himself  revealed  that  his  students  corrected  his pronunciation. I  am  talking  about  hotel  suites.

> **You  may  wear  your  suit  in the  suite**
>
> **You  may  eat   your  sweet  in  the  suite**

Is  *suite*  pronounced  as  *suit*  in any  native  English-speaking  country  or  is  it  limited to  India  alone?

Here is a link which shows how *suit* and *suite* are confusing to pronounce:
[Suite vs. Suit: Frequently Mispronounced Words](https://blog.authenticjourneys.info/2013/12/suite-vs-suit-frequently-mispronounced.html?m=1)

Comment: It is not unusual to hear it pronounced "suit" in the US, though that pronunciation would not be considered "educated".

Comment: A *three-piece **suite*** (pronounced ***sweet***) is a sofa and two armchairs (furniture). A *three-piece **suit*** (pronounced ***sute***) is a jacket, trousers, and waistcoat (formal clothing).

Comment: It's worth pointing out that Indian English is a distinct dialect of English, and there is no particular reason any particular word should be pronounced the same way as other dialects do.  (It's probably the most widely spoken 2nd language dialect of English, and there are non-trivial numbers of native speakers.) Note: I speak BrE.

Comment: You misspelled my username and as a result I wasn't notified. I just came back to visit when I saw the same spelling mistake of "pronounced" in the title. I am well, thank you for asking.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica: There are proper dialects, and there are also incorrect dialects, not just in India but also in the US. For example, "determine" is pronounced as "deter-mine" by many Indians, and "could of" and "have dove" instead of "could have" and "have dived" in certain parts of the US. The reason for such errors is simple; lack of correction from others (or refusal of correction).

Comment: @user21820: There's no such thing as an "incorrect dialect". (Some dialects are *stigmatized*, meaning that speakers of other dialects view them negatively, but that's hardly the same thing.)

Comment: @ruakh: That's just a silly excuse. If you spell "breath" wrongly as "breaf" just because nobody taught you to spell it right, then it is simply incorrect and you cannot just claim to be writing in your own peculiar dialect of English.

Comment: @user21820: Your second sentence is correct, but has nothing to do with anything else on this page. I can only conclude that you actually realize that your initial claim was untenable, and are now backpedaling . . .

Comment: @ruakh: I'm not backpedaling; that's presumptuous of you. You agree that "breaf" is wrong, not just some idiosyncratic dialect. Likewise "could of" is wrong, and it arose **for the same reason** (nobody taught them to spell "could've" right). Similarly "have dove" (nobody corrected them) and "determine", as I stated in my earlier comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The OED says "Pronunciation:
  Brit. /swiːt/
,  U.S. /swit/", so apparently this is not 'normal' anywhere.

It's an easy mistake to make, though, and I see no reason why it should be confined to India. It may be fair, however, to say that European-connected countries are more aware of French roots and pronunciation, so less likely to fall into this particular trap.

Answer (score 9):

Wells in his *Pronunciation Dictionary* has /swi:t/ (=sweet) for *suite* in both British and American English but has the following remark: *but in American English sometimes* /su:t/ *in the sense 'suite of furniture'*.

Presumably some Americans make a distinction between a *hotel suite* /swi:t/ and a *suite* /su:t/ *of furniture*.

Comment: For some reason this took hold in the Detroit/US area decades ago, where it's still common to hear radio/TV advertising offering 'bedroom suits'.

Comment: I also used to hear those TV commercials, "bedroom suite" pronounced "suit".

Comment: I can affirm that at least one major furniture dealer in Houston, Texas, during the 1960s and 1970s consistently referred to special ensembles in his commercials as "suits"—"dining room suits," "living room suits," "bedroom suits," etc.—although the spelling in the caption that appeared onscreen was always _suite_ or _suites_.

Comment: I've been in the US all my life, and never heard "suite" pronounced "*sute*".  It's always been "*sweet*".

Comment: *The Beverly Hillbillies*, which was very popular in its day, had a running joke where Miss Hathaway (the banker’s secretary) would refer to “your suite” and Jethro (the dumb nephew) would misinterpret it as “you’re sweet”. So at least one generation of Americans could be counted on for its correct pronunciation.

Comment: @SvenYargs Those cringe-inducing commercials were still running on Houston TV in the 1980s and 1990s, maybe still are running into the 2010s.

Comment: @RonJohn Me, either, but it sound like it might be regional.